# How can I merge pdf files together and take only the first page from each file?

Tags: qpdf

I am using qpdf to merge all pdf files in a directory and I would like to merge only the first page of multiple inputfiles. According to the [qpdf documentation on page selection](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html#ref.page-selection) this should be possible. I have tried couple variants without luck:

```
qpdf --empty --pages *.pdf 1-1 -- "output.pdf"
qpdf --empty --pages *.pdf 1 -- "output.pdf"
```

What can I do?

Comment: From the man page you posted, looks like you have to do `filename page-range` for all files, eg `a.pdf 1 b.pdf 1` etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in this [qpdf issue](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/issues/537#issuecomment-865937411),
the shell expands `*.pdf` in the command `qpdf --empty --pages *.pdf 1 -- "output.pdf"`, that means it replaces `*.pdf`
with a list of pdf files in the current directory. Assuming you have the following pdf files in the current directory:

- `file1.pdf`
- `file2.pdf`
- `file3.pdf`

the command becomes:

```
qpdf --empty --pages file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf 1 -- "output.pdf"
```

so the page selector is only applied to the last pdf. On a Mac or Linux you can script the command to add a `1` after
each pdf-filename, to take the first page of each pdf file and put it all together like so:

```
qpdf --empty --pages $(for i in *.pdf; do echo $i 1; done) -- output.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

For more flexibility:
`qpdf --empty --pages pdf1.pdf 1 pdf2.pdf 1 pdf3.pdf 1 -- "output.pdf"`:

you can adapt the pages to be merged by ordering the pdf input files

`qpdf --empty --pages pdf3.pdf 1 pdf1.pdf 1 pdf2.pdf 1 -- "output.pdf"`

and if needed by repeating some input source and by using more advanced page configuration:

`qpdf --empty --pages pdf3.pdf 1 pdf1.pdf 2-5,7 pdf3.pdf 6,8-10 pdf2.pdf 11 -- "output.pdf"`

Answer (score -1):

The following piece of code worked for me very well.

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader

pdf_files = []
# Get all PDF documents in current directory
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        pdf_files.append(filename)
pdf_files.sort(key=str.lower)

# Take first page from each PDF    

pdf_writer = PdfWriter()

for filename in pdf_files:
    reader = PdfReader(filename)
    page = reader.pages[0]
    pdf_writer.add_page(page)


with open("CombinedFirstPages.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    pdf_writer.write(fp)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).